# How to include CKeditor which is outside of your document root

Tags: php, apache, lamp, ckeditor

Is it possible to use CKeditor which resides outside of your document root inside document root application?

For e.g. I am having directory structure like:

```
    My Documentroot

    C://xampp/htdocs/example.com

    My CKeditor is outside and parallel to document root say

    C://xampp/lib/ckeditor
```

How can I call ckeditor.js which is in `C://xampp/lib/ckeditor/ckeditor` in my application page in `C://xampp/htdocs/example.com/editor.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Apache, you could set up an Alias in your site's `VirtualHost` section in `httpd.conf` (or `httpd-vhosts.conf`):

```
Alias /ckeditor C:/xampp/lib/ckeditor
```

as @wimvds says, the file *must* be accessible to the browser somehow.

Comment: Hi Pekka, when tried http://example.com/ckeditor gives Access forbidden! error. What could be reason?

Comment: The reason probably is a missing `<Directory "C:/xampp/lib/ckeditor">` with Allow from ... section telling Apache that it is allowed to access the folder.

Comment: @Asif It's either what @wimvds says, or the directory simply has no index.htm file. Could that be?

Answer (score 1):

Since CKEditor is Javascript it HAS to reside somewhere in your document root, otherwise you won't be able to include it.

Answer (score -1):

`../../lib/ckeditor/ckeditor`

`../` is the parent directory.

Comment: No Parent directory. As i told lib directory is parallel to my htdocs directory

Comment: the problem is that the file is outside the web root and can't be requested in a browser. Using a relative path will fail because it can't "dig" beyond the web root.